# Playbook with with_items is not going through all statements

Tags: ansible

I have this code

```
  1 - hosts: webservers
  2   remote_user: user
  3   become: yes
  4   become_method: sudo
  5   tasks:
  6
  7   - name: Adding hosts to file
  8     lineinfile:
  9                  dest=/etc/hosts
 10                  state=present
 11                  insertafter=EOF
 12                  line="someline1"
 13     with_items:
 14       - line="someline2"
 15       - line="someline3"
 16       - line="someline4"
 17       - line="someline5"
```

However, when the script runs, it only goes through two of the cases, like this and it doesnt tell me about the line in the original lineinfile function -

```
PLAY [webservers] *************************************************************

GATHERING FACTS ***************************************************************
ok: [user@11.11.11.11]

TASK: [Adding hosts to file] **************************************************
ok: [user@11.11.11.11] => (item=line="someline2")
ok: [user@11.11.11.11] => (item=line="someline3")
ok: [user@11.11.11.11] => (item=line="someline4")
ok: [user@11.11.11.11] => (item=line="someline5")

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
user@11.11.11.11        : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Someline3, 4, and 5 are not added into the file.  Any idea what the issue might be?

Comment: If you look at it, it only says 2 of the lines are ok, even though theres 5 of them there.  It only goes through the first line (inside of the lineinfile module) and then the first case inside of the with_items section.  It ignores all of the others.

Comment: It is working as expected. What are you expecting?

Comment: I was expecting it to check for each one of those lines inside of the host file, and if it didnt find them, it would add them.  Isnt the point of that statement to go through each one of those lines and check if it is inside of the file?  As it stands right now, it only goes through two of them, and ignores the other three lines even though they are not inside of the file I am trying to add them to.

Comment: No. Your code doesn't do it. Your `with_items` is incorrect. Check my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking for the same line every time. Change this to suit your needs:

```
  - name: Adding hosts to file
    lineinfile:
                 dest=/etc/hosts
                 state=present
                 insertafter=EOF
                 line={{item}}
    with_items:
      - "someline1"
      - "someline2"
      - "someline3"
      - "someline4"
      - "someline5"
```

Comment: Ahhh.  I didnt realize it had to be in {{}}'s.  Thanks.